# Vue.js render from child into parent when needed just like router-view

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, parent-child, ionic4

I'm trying to dynamically show a footer/header based on a child view in ionic

I am using the Ionic 4 framework in combination with Vue.js. Tried slots and such having the feeling i'm on the right track but not fully there yet.

I've got a Base.vue (component) which holds

```html
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-page class="ion-page" main>
        <page-header />
        <router-view />
        <page-footer />
    </ion-page>
  </ion-app>
</template>

<script>
import PageHeader from '@/components/PageHeader'
import PageFooter from '@/components/PageFooter'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'master',
  components: {
    PageHeader,
    PageFooter,
  },
}
</script>
```

As a child view i've got the following; i know that it's not the right approach to include it inside the `<ion-content>` but don't know how to set this up in the correct way:

```html
<template>
  <ion-content fullscreen>
    <page-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>
                Test
            </ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </page-header>

    <ion-content>
        <p>Schedule page</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</template>

<script>
import PageHeader from '@/components/PageHeader'

export default {
  name: 'schedule',
  components: {
    PageHeader,
  },
}
</script>
```

The header component (which should be dynamic):

```html
<template>
  <ion-header>
    <slot name="header" />
  </ion-header>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'page-header',
  }
</script>
```

What i'm trying to do is making a Base.vue with a dynamic header (PageHeader.vue) so based on a given child view i could change or extend the header if needed.

Comment: It depends, are you trying to always hide the footer and header when on this child route or are you trying to get content from the child into the header/footer?

Comment: Adding your attempt with slots would probably help people understand what you are trying to achieve, and why that attempt failed.

Comment: @StevenB. the header is normally shown in the Base.vue with just an default but on some child views i would like to add an additional <ion-toolbar> to it as for the footer there is by default none but also here in some cases i would like to add an custom one depending on the child

Comment: @ghybs the attempt is described in my question? what should i add more to make it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think you're saying you want to change the content of the page header depending on the child.

Components cannot directly affect the templates of other components in the tree. Slots give you some control over this, but it is limited to allowing a component to inject templates into sections of a child component, not the other way around.

Your options are:

1. Add logic to your parent component which detects what child component is shown and then change the page header accordingly. The page header won't be controlled directly by the child component, though.
2. Use [named views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html) with vue-router.
3. Use something like [portal-vue](https://portal-vue.linusb.org/), but don't go crazy with this kind of power...

Comment: hi Decade Moon, thats exactly what i wanted todo... it was more the idea just how a vue-router works... because that one is also putting in the content on that specific tag right? But as you describe this isn't possible todo? Also not with a render function?

as for 2 is it possible to provide a short example on how to fix this?
i will also check out your option 3 this looks good to

it's just on some child views that i would like to add an additional <ion-toolbar> and in sometimes a custom footer (normally no footer) so hopefully it works... thanks for this suggestion i'll let you know

Comment: another question; how would you solve this in option 1?

Comment: #3 is the only option which allows for the header content to be controlled completely by the child component. Is this a requirement? Otherwise #1 and #2 require separate components, so if you need to share logic/data between them then this will be something you will have to accommodate.

Comment: it's not a requirement it was more that i was thinking about this "logic" and should be fine but eventually it's more a anti-pattern right? so if you'd suggest otherwise i will try that as well but many thanks for clearing things out for me! really helped a lot